# Using Group By while Counting a Different Columns Values

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to group by job id while having it count the milliseconds in each row of the job id.

For example ill have 5 rows of job 55 all with different milliseconds like .3, .5, 1.5, .3, .4. I don't want it to display 5 rows, only one like this: 55 | 3.0

This is how far i've gotten i just need a little nudge int eh right direction.

```
SELECT job_ID, AVG_REC_TIME_MILLIS, count(AVG_REC_TIME_MILLIS)
FROM job_step js
GROUP BY js.JOB_ID;
```

Comment: Hint : `SUM` instead of `COUNT()`.

Comment: Could you please more elaborate with table format data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()` & `SELECT` statement should contains only columns which are aggregated when `GROUP BY` involved so, `AVG_REC_TIME_MILLIS` doesn't make any sense.

So, removed it from `SELECT` statement  :

```
SELECT job_ID, SUM(AVG_REC_TIME_MILLIS)
FROM job_step js
GROUP BY js.JOB_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what im looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the sum of all milliseconds for a job_id then

```
SELECT job_ID, sum(AVG_REC_TIME_MILLIS)
FROM job_step js
GROUP BY js.JOB_ID;
```

If number of job steps is what you need then consider the following query

```
SELECT job_ID, count(AVG_REC_TIME_MILLIS)
    FROM job_step js
    GROUP BY js.JOB_ID;
```